# How to use operators in subset function to drop records in R?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have dataframe like as shown below

```
test_df <- data.frame("SN" = c(1,2,3,4,5), "code" = c("ABC","DEF","GHI","JKL","MNO"), "Name" = c("John","Dora","Raja","Poda","Podi"))
```

It looks like as shown below

[image]

I would like to drop records based on multiple conditions as given below

```
sub_df <- subset(test_df, SN!="1" 
                      | !(code %in% c("GHI","MNO"))
                      | !(Name %in% c("Poda")))
```

I tried with `||`,`&`,`&&` operators but nothing helps.

Please note that in my real data of `4M`, I may not know which rows I want but I know which rows to drop. So I would prefer `not equal(!)` approach

I expect my output to be like as shown below

[image]

Comment: Looks like that you want all the conditions to be `TRUE`, so just replace `|` with `&`.

Comment: `sub_df <- subset(test_df, (SN!="1" & !code %in% c("GHI","MNO")& !Name %in% c("Poda")))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following with `&` among conditions:

```
sub_df <- test_df[test_df$SN!=1 & !(test_df$code %in% c("GHI","MNO")) & !(test_df$Name %in% c("Poda")), ]
```

Comment: Does it consider `Poda` as like operator pattern or it expects to see the full string ?

Comment: In my case 'Poda' is a full string. But if you want to use it as a pattern, for example, if you have pattern including ´Poda´, then you set your condition to `!grepl(".*?Poda.*",test_df$Name)`, which applies regexp to filter out elements @SSMK

Answer (score 1):

Given your expected output, you should use `&` and not `|`.

Below is a `data.table` solution.

**Code**

```
require(data.table); setDT(test_df)

restr = quote(SN != 1 & !(code %in% c('GHI', 'MNO')) & !(Name %in% c("Poda"))) #Define your restrictions

df = test_df[eval(restr)] # Apply restrictions
```

**Result**

```
> df
   SN code Name
1:  2  DEF Dora
```

Comment: You can also apply the restrictions directly in place of `eval(restr)` in `test_df[eval(restr)]`, i.e. `df = test_df[SN != 1 & !(code %in% c('GHI', 'MNO')) & !(Name %in% c("Poda"))]`. I just like to declare the restrictions separately for cleanliness.